# Convert Stream of Collection<String[]> to List<String>[]

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a piece of code:

```
table.stream().filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber]))
.map(row -> row[keyColumnNumber]).map(hash::get)
```

The last step: `.map(hash::get)` returns `Collection<String[]>`. and as a result I need to collect all of that to List.

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

returns List> what is expected, but

```
.flatMap(Stream::of).collect(Collectors.toList()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

returns the same result.

Comment: You have a lot of typos here.

Comment: Sorry, I typed code by hands, not copied

Comment: `map(hash::get)` returns `Stream<String[]>` or `Stream<Collection<String[]>>`?

Comment: @Fairy You can still edit your own question to correct those typos. It's not just for us, but for everyone: a question full of typos will be badly received, while a correct question can generate more and better-quality answers

Comment: Should the final result by a `List<String>` or `List<String[]>`?

Comment: I fixed types. `map(hash::get)` returns `Stream<Collection<String[]>>`. The result should be `List<String[]>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flatMap like so :

```
List<String> list = table.stream()
        .map(row -> hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber]))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. The final result looks like: `table.stream().filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber])).map(row -> row[keyColumnNumber])
                .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(hash.get(x).toArray(new String[0][0]))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Fairy Err, don't do that. You are converting a `Collection<String[]>` into `String[][]`, then flatten it back to `String[]`.

Comment: @Fairy It's better to use [@Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51262529/5558072) solution if the result should be `List<String[]>`

Comment: When `hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber])` returns `false`, the subsequent `hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber])` (her split into two operations), will return `null`. This doesn’t sound very useful. I suppose, the actual intention is to accept the elements where `containsKey` return `true`. Generally, it’s more efficient to use only `get` without a preceding `containsKey`: `table.stream().map(row -> hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber])).filter(Objects::nonNull) .flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4):

If

```
table.stream().filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber]))
.map(row -> row[keyColumnNumber]).map(hash::get)
```

returns a `Stream<Collection<String[]>>` and you require a `List<String[]>`, you do need `flatMap`:

```
List<String[]> result = table.stream()
        .filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber]))
        .map(row -> row[keyColumnNumber])
        .map(hash::get) // Stream<Collection<String[]>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<String[]>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<String[]>
```

It should be possible to join the `map` and `flatMap` calls into a single `flatMap`, as Aomine commented:

```
List<String[]> result = table.stream()
        .filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber]))
        .flatMap(row -> hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber]).stream()) // Stream<String[]>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<String[]>
```

Comment: "_It might be possible to join the map and flatMap calls into a single flatMap, but it's hard to tell without knowing the type of table and row[keyColumnNumber]._" wouldnt it just be `.flatMap(row -> hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber]).stream())`?

Comment: @Aominè that’s right, but note the similarity to the preceding `containsKey` operation. I’d rather eliminate *that*, but then, you’d need a `null` check after get again, i.e. `table.stream().map(row -> hash.get(row[keyColumnNumber])).filter(Objects::nonNull) .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());` Btw., I reversed the logic to keep the non-`null` elements rather than the `null`s (equivalent to `containsKey` rather than `!containsKey`)…

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it can solve...

```
List<String> list = table.stream().filter(row -> !hash.containsKey(row[keyColumnNumber]))
  .map(row -> row[keyColumnNumber]) 
  .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(hash.get()))//<<-----------------
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```